# How can I integrate searching functionality on table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

At the moment, all the available flights that was received from API are successfully loaded on the page. However, I would like to enable the end user to search specific flight, let's say, by `flight number` and `departure date`. How can I integrate this searching functionality in the existing codes?

**FlightPage.js**

```
 render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h2>Flights</h2>
        {this.props.loading ? (
          <div>Loading...</div>
        ) : (
          <FlightList flights={this.props.flights} />
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see the bellow code,  I have used table to present the results.I would like to show only one result or blank table when searching is applied. Can you help me to achieve this?

**FlightList.js**

```
const FlightList = ({ flights }) => (
  <table className="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th />
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Provider</th>
        <th>Dest</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {flights.map((f, i) => {
        return (
          <tr key={i}>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name="flightListCheckbox" />
            </td>
            <td>{f.date}</td>
            <td>{f.pnr}</td>
            <td>{f.flightNumber}</td>
          </tr>
        );
      })}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);
```

Comment: How about filtering `flights` before rendering `FlightList`, what have you tried?

Comment: I want the results to be shown on the page by default. Then, the user can search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `input` for search and filter `flights` by value of input. Try this

```
class FlightPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    keyword: '',
  }

  ...

  getFlights = () => {
    const { keyword } = this.state
    const { flights } = this.props

    return flights.filter(flight => flight.name.includes(keyword)) // name or something else
  }

  onInputChange = e => {
    this.setState({ keyword: e.target.value })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <>
        <input onChange=(this.onInputChange) value={this.state.keyword} />
        <FlightList flights={this.getFlights()} />
      </>
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `filter` to create a searching functionality like
I would at first add an input where I can insert my filter values

**FlightPage.js**

```
handleInput: (event) => {
  const { name, value } = event.target

  this.setState({ [name]: value })
}

render () {
  const { filter } = this.state
  return (
    <>
      <input onChange=(this.handleInput) value={filter} name='filter' />
      <FlightList flights={this.props.flights} filterValues={filter} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Then I would use my state to filter my Object like

**FlightList.js**

```
const FlightList = ({ flights, filterValue }) => {

const filterdFlights = flights.filter(flight => Object.values(flight).includes(filterValue))

return (
  <table className="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th />
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Provider</th>
        <th>Dest</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {filterdFlights.map((f, i) => {
        return (
          <tr key={i}>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name="flightListCheckbox" />
            </td>
            <td>{f.date}</td>
            <td>{f.pnr}</td>
            <td>{f.flightNumber}</td>
          </tr>
        );
      })}
    </tbody>
  </table>
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) your `flights` array using `flights.filter` or [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) it using `flights.sort`.

Answer (score -2):

You could try to use jquery datatable. It adds a lot of funcionality to tables easy to implement.

[DataTable doc](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: Why should we use another JS Libary when we already use react this is not necessary.